# "Invalid XPath selection inside field node. Cannot find .." error while loading a schema into the dataset

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset

I want to add an XML schema(Main.xsd) to a dataset which includes another schema(base.xsd) defining the complex types used in the former one.

The Main.xsd has a block defining xs:unique with selector and field to uniquely define a particular element as the primary key. 
Here is the Main.xsd:

```
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Main.xsd" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop"  targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Main.xsd"  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="3.0.4 01-07-2011">

<xs:include schemaLocation="base.xsd"/>

<xs:complexType name="Employees">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="EmployeeID" type="UE_SignedInt"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Report" type=" Employees" />

<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref=" Report " />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:unique name="ReportConst" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
  <xs:selector xpath=".//Report" />
  <xs:field xpath="EmployeeID" />
</xs:unique>
</xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

The type “UE_SignedInt” is defind in the base.xsd which is included in Main.xsd.

Now , when I try to include Main.xsd into a dataset, it throws an error: “Invalid XPath selection inside field node. Cannot find EmployeeID” as EmployeeID uses the type which is defined in the base.xsd.

If I use some basic type like “xs:int” to this element , the loading into the dataset works fine. Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved when I modifed the unique block as:

```
<xs:unique name="ReportConst" msdata:PrimaryKey="true"> 
<xs:selector xpath="." /> 
<xs:field xpath="EmployeeID" /> 
</xs:unique>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the namespace of the UE_SignedInt element.

```
    <xs:element name="EmployeeID" type="xxx:UE_SignedInt"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But the "EmployeeId" uses the same namespace of the Main.xsd schema. So, we don have to mention the namespace explicitly